# prove this inequality for $a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}=1$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}>0(n>1)$,such $a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}=1$,show that
$$\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{2}}{a_{3}}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{1}}\ge a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}$$

when $n=2$,$$\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}\ge a_{1}+a_{2}$$
or
$$a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}\ge\dfrac{1}{2}(a_{1}+a_{2})^2\ge a_{1}+a_{2}$$
since $$a_{1}+a_{2}\ge 2\sqrt{a_{1}a_{2}}=2$$
and
$n=3$,because use AM-GM 
$$\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{2}}{a_{3}}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{a^2_{1}}{a_{2}a_{3}}}=3a_{1}$$
so
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{2}}{a_{3}}\ge 3\sum_{cyc}a_{1}$$
so
$$\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{a_{2}}{a_{3}}+\dfrac{a_{3}}{a_{1}}\ge a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}$$
But for $n\ge 4$,I can't prove it.Thanks

Comment: It is wrong for n large engough.

If n=2m and $a_1=a_2=...=a_m=2,a_{m+1}=..=a_{2m}=\frac12$. The left side is $2(m-1)+4+\frac14$ but the right side is $\frac52 m$

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu you can add this as an answere

Comment: It's already wrong for $n=4$ using, for example
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=\left(\frac{4}{3}.\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{12},27\right)$$

Comment: Oh,Thanks,  so  which $n$ is holde?  other words,  $n=5$ is right?

Comment: @geromty:$\;$It fails for all $n\ge 4$.